# C# Sql query with unnamed parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = {0} AND Column2 = {1}
```

And I want to execute that statement and send a list of parameters that contains values which should replace {0} and {1}. A list of objects with 2 elements.

I have only found solution with named parameters by now, but I dont want named parameters, I want to do it in the way specified above...

Comment: You can use String.Format() and replace {0},{1} with parameter value.

Comment: Thanks. i didn't remember that, it works.

Comment: Why You don't want to use `parameterized query`? It's really bad approach and opens your app for SQL injection attack.

Comment: By the way, `string.Format` does **not** prevent SQL Injection attacks. Consider to using parameterized statements instead.

Comment: @RahulSingh is correct non-parameterized queries are vulnerable to Sql injection attack .

Comment: Thanks on advice, but only in this specific case which we are working on we must use this approach. And only admin will have access to that route, there wont be sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This string looks like format string for `String.Format` and has nothing to do with parameterized query.

Basically you shouldn't use `String.Format` and other string concatenation operations to create sql query since it leads to sql injection.

Using parameterized queries with `SqlCommand.Parameters` is safer way, consider using it.